# How can I join a table to itself to get the values needed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

So I have a table that I'm trying to join to and I'm not quite getting everything I need. So I have a table that looks like this. I want to see if there is a way to join this table to itself to get the rest, so I see that when I see the code '0013' then I should be getting a code of '0013' code_type of '9_prcdr'  and med_code_ID of 74717. I've tried to join this to itself, but I'm either not getting enough rows or getting too many. I've looked online and I see there is a function I could try which is lead or lag, but I don't have too much experience with it. Could you help? Thank you!

```
patient_id claim_id  from_dt    prcdr_cd code   code_type  med_code_ID
123        961      2004-02-14  0013     0013   9_prcdr  74717  
456        214      2004-02-21  0013     NULL   NULL     NULL   
789        961      2004-01-16  0013     0013   9_prcdr  74717  
1001       212      2004-09-24  0013     NULL   NULL     NULL   
10002      291      2004-10-02  0013     NULL   NULL     NULL
```

This is what it should look like.

```
patient_id claim_id  from_dt    prcdr_cd code   code_type  med_code_ID
123        961      2004-02-14  0013     0013   9_prcdr  74717  
456        214      2004-02-21  0013     0013   9_prcdr  74717  
789        961      2004-01-16  0013     0013   9_prcdr  74717  
1001       212      2004-09-24  0013     0013   9_prcdr  74717  
10002      291      2004-10-02  0013     0013   9_prcdr  74717
```

And my attempt was this :

```
select * 
from t1
INNER JOIN t1 t2 ON t1.code =  t2.prcdr_cd
    AND t1.patient_id = t2.patient_id 
    AND t1.claim_id = t2.claim_id
    AND t1.from_dt = t2.from_dt
```

Comment: Its still not clear (to me) what you are trying to do? If you `select *` from a table joined on itself, you will get each column duplicated, once from the `from` and once from the `join` - you have not shown this. Your criteria for filling in the missing information also isn't clear, your join attempt to join based on `patient_id` which is unique, so if `code` is null then it will stay null. So for example you need to clarify how `patient_id` 456 should be obtaining the missing values i.e. from which row, based on what logic.

Comment: What happens when you have multiple values for the same code? Pick the max, min, any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you can use window functions:

```
select
    patient_id,
    claim_id,
    from_dt,
    prcdr_cd,
    max(code)        over(partition by prcdr_cd) code,
    max(code_type)   over(partition by prcdr_cd) code_type,
    max(med_code_ID) over(partition by prcdr_cd) med_code_ID
from t1
```

This assumes that there a given `prcdr_cd` correspond to a unique tuple of values of `code`, `code_type` and `med_code_ID`.